# How can I get named parameters in Java in static methods?

Tags: java

Should I implement named parameters in Java using Hash tables?

I saw this entry:

[Named Parameter idiom in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java)

: but I did not want to use the builder method which seemed overly verbose

Comment: a map of type Map<String, Object> can be used for this

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want named parameters that look very readable. Have you ever seen Ruby's named parameters as a good example?

I guess I didn't want to mention Ruby in the question though as I want to see what different techniques there are, and not get into a language debate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as named parameters in Java.

There are [workarounds](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=118828) and there have been submissions in [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/) but they were rejected. Sun is well aware that there is a demand but, so far, they have rejected any such language change.

Using Maps as suggested above is a possibility but unless all your arguments have the same type, it is cumbersome. And it's not really efficient either.