# TestNG - How to avoid checkstyle error when number of parameters exceeds 7?

Tags: java, testng, parameter-passing, checkstyle, testng-annotation-test

When number of arguments to a method exceeds 7, checkstyle error (i.e., 
More than 7 parameters (found 8). [ParameterNumber]) would be thrown. Hence, for below method also it is throwing. **Generally**, checkstyle error can be avoided by using String array or Hashmap.

But, how to avoid here **being the method arguments having @Optional annotation**?

```
@Parameters({ "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8" })
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(@Optional("value1") String test1, @Optional("value2") String test2, @Optional("value3") String test3, @Optional("value4") String test4, @Optional("value5") String test5, @Optional("value6") String test6, @Optional("value7") String test7, @Optional("value8") String test8) {
    ....
}
```

**One way is to increase the parameter limit in checkstyle.xml.**

> But, looking for if there is any better solution.

Comment: First of all, not recommended to use too many parameters in same method. See  https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3553, also you can use builder pattern - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272756/handling-more-than-7-parameters,

Comment: How to fit builder pattern for testng? Example please..

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

1)
Disable the check and not validate the number of parameters in methods.

2)
Increase `max` for the check thereby allowing you to have all methods with the new limit.

3)
Suppress the violation with a filter for this one location. https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html . If you want to target methods that use `Optional`, then I would try to use https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter .

Comment: Is there any way similar to builder pattern to decrease number of arguments, that works out for TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class which holds your parameters.

### Wrapper class:

```
public class ParameterObject {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;
    private String test4;
    private String test5;
    private String test6;
    private String test7;
    private String test8;

    public ParameterObject() {
       super();
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    //add more getter and setter.
}
```

### Test method:

```
public void beforeTest(ParameterObject parameters) {
    //access parameters with:
    parameters.getTest1();
    //...
}
```

---

You can also use the builder pattern with this wrapper class.

Comment: What about Optional annotation & Parameter annotation values?

Answer (score 0):

You could use varargs. That allows you to specify an array as a parameter including none.

Comment: How is it possible to do it so without avoiding @Optional annotation usage?

Comment: I missed that part of your question. Not familiar with TestNg, anyway.