# Using Named Parameters in java Class

Tags: java

I have a use case to use named and optional parameter.I tried to use named parameter as in a tutorial but it doesn't work

My code  is

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
  {
     System.out.println((CalculateBMI(weight= 123, height: 64));
  }
  public static int CalculateBMI(int weight, int height)
  {
      return (weight * 703) / (height * height);
  }
```

getting Error "  weight cannot be resolved to a variable" 
Please help

Comment: also the main method is spelled with a non-capital m

Comment: Please post the URL to the tutorial, so we can correct the original author. (This wouldn't even be valid C#, as you've got `weight = ` rather than `weight:`.)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably reading the wrong tutorial, Java doesn't support neither named nor optional parameters.

## See also:

- [Named Parameter idiom in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016)
- [Java optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best you can do:

```
int weight = 123; 
int height = 64;    
System.out.println((CalculateBMI(weight, height));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support named parameters. Groovy, which compiles to Java byte code **does** have named parameters. Also you can compile Java source files using Groovy (not recommended as you will not benefit from the features of Groovy).

Answer (score 0):

code is:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CalculateBMI(123,64));
}

public static int CalculateBMI(int weight, int height) {
    return (weight * 703) / (height * height);
}
```

Comment: You could just edit (=bugfix) your answer, and my comments would disappear ;)

Comment: @jlordo: The *compiler* won't care that the method is called `main` rather than `Main`. It's a perfectly valid name. It's only when you try to use the class an entry point that it'll be a problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet correct, the compiler won't care, but this is obviously a main method that the OP wants to execute. And i doubt he wants to write a `main` method which calls his `Main` method :)

Comment: @jlordo: Sure - but if you're going to pick nits, it's at least worth picking them carefully :)