# What design pattern does these code follow?

Tags: java, jquery

in jQuery we often do this:

```
$('#el1').css('margin-left','5px').attr('title','test title').removeClass('class1');
```

in Java StringBuilder, same as above：

```
StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder();  
builder.append("str1").insert(0, 'A').deleteCharAt(2);
```

So, what design pattern does this code follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an application of [the fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern.

Comment: ...and it was a brilliant idea. [Martin Fowler's article](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) on it is somewhat more descriptive than Wikipedia.

Comment: I though it was a Builder design pattern as sated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza [builders frequently use a fluent interface.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Useful_tips) `StringBuilder` is a fluent builder for `String`s, which should come as absolutely no surprise to you.

Answer (score 0):

Its called as method chaining/named parameter idiom in OOP language.
Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: I disagree with you and the Wikipedia article in calling this "named parameters." **This** is named parameters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java

Comment: That's funny, because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java#comment1905024_1988035

Comment: The wiki article which I mentioned in answer calls it "Named Parameter Idiom" also :)

Comment: I already mentioned that you're not the only one I disagree with on this.