# Clever way for a method to accept any combination of unique objects as parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, constructor, parameter-passing

I have a class that can be constructed with a `String`, `Record`, and `Criteria`. Is there any way to allow the method signature to accept these parameters in any order (other than creating multiple constructors)? This is more of an academic question than anything.

Comment: Not unless you want to use `instanceof` and do casting everywhere.

Comment: Not in a way that makes any kind of sense.

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? No offense. Just can't see a use case right now.

Comment: @raffael, I was just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) mentions no such easy way.

You can always pass `Object`s and perform type checks yourself, but that's a wrong approach.

Java does not [allow named parameters (ways around it in link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create some class which holds and represents those three parameters, but I would only suggest that if the three parameters were related in such a way as to make logical sense in an object model.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
public class MyClass ()
{

  private String _str;
  private Record _rec;
  private Criteria _crit;

  public MyClass ()
  {
    _rec = null;
    _crit = null;
    _str = null;
  }

  public MyClass string (String str)
  {
    this._str = str;
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass record (Record rec)
  {
    this._rec = rec;
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass criteria (Criteria crit)
  {
    this._crit = crit;
    return this;
  }

  public static void getInstance ()
  {
    return new MyClass ();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     MyClass instance = MyClass.getInstance ().string("something").criteria(someCriteria).record(someRecord);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize the fields to null, the default value is null anyways