# How to design constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

Lets assume a class `Foo` with 2 instance variables, int x and int y. The use case demands I can construct the class with either none, single or all params.

```
input X    input Y

  0         0           no constuctor

  0          1          public Foo(int x);

  1          0          public Foo(int y);

  1          1          public Foo(int x, int y);
```

Now whats the convention/best practices in this case. Do I need to add all the permutations of constructors ? If yes, the it would result in exponential growth. If No, then whats solution ?

Comment: You can't have `Foo(int x)` and `Foo(int y)` as separate constructors in the same class since they have identical signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It depends.

Longer answer: Add the ones that correspond with real use cases. If that means one with all parameters, or one with none (which sets defaults for the parameters), great. If there are common use cases for having some parameters default and some not, provide constructors for that.

Note that you cannot have multiple constructors with the same order, number, and types of parameters.

Comment: +1 for *it depends*. I'm using it for every answer from now on, with citation of course!

Comment: It's not always the best answer, but the question was in danger of being too focused and missing the general point. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to use the builder pattern as in

```
new FooBuilder().build()   // Uses default values for both parameters

new FooBuilder().setX(42).build()  // Uses default value for y

new FooBuilder().setY(-13).build()  // Uses default value for x

new FooBuilder().setX(42).setY(-13).build()  // Supplied values for both
```

and then your builder might look like

```
class FooBuilder {
  public Foo build() { return new Foo(...); }
  public FooBuilder setX(int x) { ...; return this; }
  public FooBuilder setY(int y) { ...; return this; }
}
```

Comment: In your suggested solution too you need to have methods like setX,setY and so on....

Comment: @Rupesh, Yes.  The builder has setters.  The built class does not.

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that you can have mutable Builders that create immutable objects. You can also do away with the `set` part of method names to give a sometimes more readable approach: `new FooBuilder().x(42).y(-13).build();` (obviously depends on one's style/preference). Finally, my favorite benefit of the builder pattern is that you can create simpler constructors in the _built_ object because the Builder exists for the complexities of constructing the built object, which should give a cleaner and more testable API, assuming people don't mind builders of course.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach for this kind of case is to use the *builder* pattern.

The idea with the builder is that you have an intermediate object that understands the various required or optional arguments and is used to produce an appropriately constructed object. It means you only need to have the all-args constructor in your actual business object, which can greatly simplify things.

You use the builder by doing something like this:

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder().withX(10).withY(25).build();
```

Project Lombok provides a very helpful `@Builder` annotation that will take care of all this for you: See http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Builder.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

As @Platinum Azure says, it depends. Since you haven't said that there is a dominant use-case ...

Remember that as a class designer, we are designing for *our client programmer*. How clear will their code be *to a third person*? How would they know the meaning of

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo(2);
Foo foo23 = new Foo(2,3);
```

And what style of code you want them to follow? The "everythingononeline" style:

```
Foo foo = new Foo().setNumHeads(2).setNumLegs(3);
```

Which, when there are many things to set, can be adapted to

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
    .setNumHeads(2)
    .setNumLegs(3);
```

Or the traditional OO style:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setNumHeads(2)
foo.setNumLegs(3);
```

Then, how much work do you need to do *now*? Do you need a builder, or is `Foo` simple enough to do without (as in the above examples)?

Another way is to supply defaults:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Foo.DefaultNumHeads, Foo.DefaultNumLegs, Foo.DefaultNumTails);
```

which works well with a few arguments, but can be error prone when there are many if the defaults are defined as `int`s. So you can apply a variant of the named argument idiom. This is where some suggest a builder, as in [Named Parameter idiom in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java), or

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Foo.DefaultNumHeads, Foo.DefaultNumLegs, Foo.DefaultNumTails);
```

where `Foo.DefaultNumHeads` etc are defined as `final` objects. By the time you get to

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Foo.NumHeads(2), Foo.NumLegs(3), Foo.NumTails(5));
```

you are writing a builder inside of `Foo`.

And what style of constructor is common in the ecosystem `Foo` lives in? If other classes already have similar arguments, then maybe `Foo` should too.

The point about combinatorial explosion depends on what change can be expected to `Foo`. We get a combinatorial explosion if `Foo` is a not-well-thought-through abstraction *and* we go back and change `Foo` again and again in violation of the [Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Don't do it.

So, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Have a constructor that accepts list/array of object. Iterate over it in your constructor and set the values according to your need. I am assuming that you have setter for all the fields available in your class.

**Pros**: you need not write different constructors

**Cons**: you need to know and understand that your index or position in list/array decides which field to set.

```
Foo (Object[] args){
this.setX(args[0]); // have null check accordingly
this.setY(args[1]);    
}
```

Comment: Cons should also include unnecessary boxing/unboxing, and loss of static type checking.