# Why does Gson toJson always return null?

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

When I try to convert a basic object to json, it seems to return null with everything I have tried. What's wrong?

#### Person.java

```
public class Person {
    public String Name;
    public String Address;
}
```

#### Main code

```
Person person = new Person() {
    {
        Name = "John";
        Address = "London";
    }
};

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonPerson = gson.toJson(person);
```

Comment: Is not working because you don't have a constructor on your base class...just add a parameter less constructor after `Address` e.g: `Person(){}` and try again...

Comment: post actual compilable code, at the very least

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer, just because OP is a beginner doesn't make this a bad question, and it certainly doesn't make my answer bad. Flag / vote to close as duplicate if you want

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Gson doesn't support serializing anonymous types.

See the duplicate linked by Sotirios Delimanolis. Note that the double brace initializer you were using effectively creates an anonymous subclass, which has some nasty side effects like creating new classes every time you use it, and breaking things like Gson.

It would work if you created a constructor like this:

```
class Ideone
{
    public class Person {
        public String Name;
        public String Address;

        public Person(String Name, String Address) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Address = Address;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Person person = new Person("John", "London");

        // System.out.println(person.Name);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonPerson = gson.toJson(person);
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, you should not name your fields with capital letters; begin classes with capital letters and fields with lowercase letters.

[Have a look at the Google Java Style Guide for a good reference on naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: That's strange, it was compiling for me, not throwing an exception and proceeding to code after those statements.
Your solution has fixed it for me though so thanks for that and the style guide document

Comment: -1 you forgot about Java's initializer blocks (see [the question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1988268/1521179)), which are frequently used to *simulate* named arguments for constructors. [See this actually runnable version of your code](https://ideone.com/mHWoD8) that uses an initializer block as in OP's question, and declares the nested `Person` class as static so that it can be referenced in `main`.

Answer (score 5):

The way you are instantiating your object creates an anonymous class so you loose the type.  You can instead use a `TypeToken` to fix this as follows

```
Type personType = new TypeToken<Person>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonPerson = gson.toJson(person, personType);
```