# retrieving only certain properties when building a list of objects

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I recently switch from C# to Java and not able to solve this problem. I am automation UI using selenium. I like to build a model for a list of elements on a page, retrieve property and then work with these properties. In the example bellow, I am searching on amazon.com and getting a list of results. I have `SearchResultsModel` class which represents every item returned, `public List<SearchResultModel> GetAllResults(bool title = false;bool isPrime = false;bool price = false)` method which retrieves data from UI and place it my model, it has default parameters which allows me to manipulate what data I want to retrieve instead of retrieving everything. Then I invoking by  `List<SearchResultModel> actual = myPage.GetAllResults(title:true,isPrime:true);` in this instance I get a list of SearchResultsModel that each contain only 2 properties - title and isPrime.

In ideal world I should retrieve all the data from the page but it takes lots of time to do so and defeats the whole purpose of automation of being faster then manual testing.

I could use method overload but then I end up with tens or even hundreds methods. In this example I have only 3 property so I will end up having 9 methods, in case of an object with 10 properties, I am afraid to even do a math. I could use varagrs but then building an argument will become a mess. 
I am not sure how to solve this problem in Java. Please advise

```
public class SearchResultsModel
{
    //model that represents a single search result item 
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public boolean IsPrime{get;set;}
    public float Price {get;set;]

} 


//method to retrieve all the search results from UI
public List<SearchResultModel> GetAllResults(bool title = false;bool isPrime = false;bool price = false)
{
    List<SearchResultModel> toReturn = new List<SearchResultModel>();
    IList<IWebElement> results =  driver.FindElements(By.css("my locattors"))

    foreach(IWebElement element in results)
    {
        SearchResultModel result = new SearchResultModel();
        result.Title = title? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).GetText(): null;
        result.IsPrime = isPrime? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).Selected(): false;
        result.Price = price? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).GetText(): null;
        toReturn.Add(result);
    }

    return toReturn;
}

//this is how I can invoke objects only with a specific properties

List<SearchResultModel> actual = myPage.GetAllResults(title:true,isPrime:true);

foreach(SearchResultModel model in actual)
{
    Assert.That(model.isPrime == true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would build a class that represents what options you want to search for. It's basically a parallel to your `SearchResultsModel`. You pass an instance of that class into the `GetAllResults` method and then check each property's value to see if it should be pulled or not.

An example of the options class

```
public class SearchResultsOptions
{
    public boolean Title{get;set;}
    public boolean IsPrime{get;set;}
    public boolean Price {get;set;]
    ...
}
```

An adapted version of your `GetAllResults` method

```
public List<SearchResultModel> GetAllResults(SearchResultsOptions searchResultsOptions)
{
    List<SearchResultModel> toReturn = new List<SearchResultModel>();
    IList<IWebElement> results =  driver.FindElements(By.css("my locattors"))

    foreach(IWebElement element in results)
    {
        SearchResultModel result = new SearchResultModel();
        result.Title = searchResultsOptions.Title? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).GetText(): null;
        result.IsPrime = searchResultsOptions.IsPrime? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).Selected(): false;
        result.Price = searchResultsOptions.Price? element.FindElement(By.css("some locator")).GetText(): null;
        // add more fields here

        toReturn.Add(result);
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

You would have to instantiate the options class and then pass it to your method

```
SearchResultsOptions searchResultsOptions = new SearchResultsOptions(true, false, true);
List<SearchResultModel> searchResultsModel = GetAllResults(searchResultsOptions);
```

Comment: thanks @JeffC, to extend your logic, I can provide booleans in ```public List<SearchResultModel> GetAllResults(boolean title, boolean isPrime, boolean isPrice)``` and then invoke by ```GetAllResults(true, false,true)```. Honestly that is not an ideal method since if a model is pretty large, lets say 15 properties, then I will need to pass 15 booleans as an argument in a proper order, which is pretty easy to mess up. Again, thanks for your answer, I wish there would be a cleaner way(maybe it is language limitation)

Comment: Yeah... in C# you can use named parameters which makes everything easier to read so you are less likely to pass a value to the wrong parameter. Java doesn't have that. You could use the Builder Pattern in Java to create your options instance and then pass it to the method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988016/named-parameter-idiom-in-java/9571371) for a good example.

Comment: To your first point... yes you could do it that way but if you package up all the options in a class, it's reusable. I use this method all the time to group say Customer info like first name, last name, address, phone numbers, email, etc. I make one instance and then I can pass the same instance to 5 different methods. A huge advantage and time saver. Creating the instance can be a pain but there's really no way around that.