# Using kotlin overloaded method parameters with same data type in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, overloading, optional-parameters

I have a kotlin code/library that will end up being used in Java, one of the methods there is:

```kotlin
@JvmOverloads
fun sample(
    param1: ByteArray,
    param2: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(),
    param3: ByteArray = customMethod()
): ByteArray { ... }
```

Since the method is overloaded (`@JvmOverloads`), how do I use it in java with only `sample(param1, param3)`, excluding `param2`?

Java detects the second parameter in `sample(param1, param3)` as `param2`, rather than `param3` considering that they are of the same data type.

Do I really have to resort to `null`s or perhaps an empty `byte[]` just to skip over the part?

**I have tried:**

- Resorting to `null`s and do checks based on that, so now I have `sample(param1, null, param2);`.
- Using empty `byte[]` to skip over the part, so now I have `sample(param1, byte[], param2);`.

But, I want/prefer to have `param2` undefined/skipped rather than being defined at all.

**What I have researched (but haven't tried)**

- Data classes as parameters(?)

  ```kotlin
  fun sample(param: DataClass): ByteArray { ... }
  ```

  - However ["Don't use data classes in an API"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-api-guidelines-backward-compatibility.html#don-t-use-data-classes-in-an-api)
- This code:

  ```java
  Foo foo = new Foo() {{
      color = red;
      name = "Fred";
      size = 42;
  }};
  ```

  > from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988268/16171990

  But I don't think they are desirable (last resort maybe?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since the method is overloaded (@JvmOverloads), how do I use it in java with only sample(param1, param3), excluding param2?

You can't. `@JvmOverloads` only generates overloads with parameters from first to last. So you can call with `param1` and `param2`, but not with `param1` and `param3`.

You could swap the order of parameters around, but that only works if you don't also need the param 1 & 2 version somewhere else. Or, you could manually add an overload that only takes 1 & 3 and call that from java:

`fun sample2(param1: ByteArray, param3: ByteArray) = sample(param1, param3 = param3)`

This one should have a different name (or you could confuse with with the param 1 & 2 version), and it doesn't need the default for `param3` (because just use the original method).